# JAVA truncate scanner input

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, number-formatting, truncate

I have a program that asks the user for an input which is an int(using a scanner).
I only want the program to take in 7 digits.
If the input is not 7 digits I want to truncate it to 7 digits.

So if the number were 12345678 I would want it to be 1234567.

Currently I am storing the input in an array like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i > 7; i++)
  {
    numbers[i] = input1 % 10; 
    input1 /= 10;
    System.out.print(numbers[i]);
    //stores the numbers backwards so if input was 123, first element would be 3, 2, 1
  }
```

so that's when I run into the problem if I enter 12345678, it will store it as 8765432. I want it to store as 7654321 instead.

If anyone has any suggestions on my loop making the number store as 1234567 or 7654321, it would be quite helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way can be to save the input into a String
Then check if `length>7`, if yes keep the 7 first character, if no, do nothing ;)

```
String input1 = sc.nextLine();
if(input1.length>7){
   input1 = input1.substring(0,7);
}
int input = Integer.valueOf(input1);
```

It's clearly easier than storing each digit individually or iterate over the input ;)

**Edit** with '?' (['?' definition and explication](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html))

```
String input1 = sc.nextLine();
int input = Integer.valueOf(((input1.length>7) ? input1.substring(0,7) : input1);
```

This allows to not change the value of `input1` this will stay the original input

Comment: @megabowser56 No probs ;) I add another way, as easy than the first

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are several things.

First of all, I think it'd be better for you to use `ArrayList` and work on `Integers`, rather than primitive types such as int. If you use `ArrayList`, then you can simply do `.add(Integer e)` to put next `Integer` into your list.

Next thing, your loop should be:
`for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)` instead of `for(int i = 0; i > 7; i++)`. See the difference? If you are using `i++`, then you limit your loop with a `<`, not `>`.

As for reversing the input, it's pretty simple, use `i--` instead, but I think you can figure this out yourself.

Answer (score -1):

public static void trauncateNumber(int input1) {

```
String Str=Integer.toString(input1);
//int changeValue=0;
if(Str.length()>7){
    //Str=Integer.toString(input1);
    Str=Str.substring(0, 7);
    input1=Integer.parseInt(Str);
}
//int changeValue=
System.out.println(input1);
```

}